# MySQL data import/restore

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am running a local instance of 32-bit MySQL Server 5.7.22 with Workbench 6.3.8 (had to pick the 32-bit versions--so, older) on Windows 7 (x86).

I am importing a dumpfile.sql file.

```
 1. Import from self-contained (dump) file (.SQL)
 2. Click Start Import
 3. As the import is being performed the progress bar
 never increments or shows any progress. 
It's been running for many hours and only says "starting".
```

When I stopped the Import and refresh my schemas, I saw the db which I am trying to import but with incomplete tables and data, which is frustrating/confusing.

What am I missing in this process?

Comment: A couple of questions -> How big is your dumpfile.sql? Have you run out of disk space while restoring? Is the dumpfile.sql in proper format?

Comment: It's a .sql file, that's all I know. I have not run out of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to do this. Use `mysqldump` to take the dump and `mysql` command to restore. It works as simple as follows:

Taking the dump

`mysqldump -uroot -prootpw -h127.0.0.1 | gzip > alldatabases.sql.gz`

Restoring the dump

`gunzip -c alldatabases.sql.gz | mysql -uroot -prootpw -h127.0.0.1`

Please refer to the following bug - https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=54370. People have faced this problem before. If you have access to command line, doing this there makes more sense as that would give you a lot of flexibility around.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, the progress bar does not work in any workbench version, it always "jumps" from 0% to 100% when finished. So no need to worry about.

Second, how big is the dump file you try to import? If it's couple of gigabytes, then it might just be reasonable to take that long, especially if it's running on an older, slower machine.

If you can access the file system on the machine, you could check the [slow query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html), which is in `c:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data\{host_name}-slow.log` by default on windows. There might be something in the dump that making it so slow, and the log should show it.

If you don't have access to the logs, you can also cut up the dump to pieces by hand, and try to find the part which slowing you down.

There's no definitive answer to your question without seeing the whole dump, but hopefully these trick might help you out.

Comment: Yes the slowness I get. Why am I only getting partial data?